# Excel text only recognizing month

Tags: excel, macos

I have a date stored as "01.12.19" (which is equal to 43435)and displayed as "Dec 2019".

I want to transform it as text using =TEXTE(P11;"mm/yy") to output "12/19".

However, Excel only recognizes the month, as it outputs "12/yy". I could not find any explanations online.

Anyone where knows what is going on? Thanks

Comment: I believe you want `"mm/jj"`

Answer (score 1):

Please try "mm/rr", this should solve your issue.

If not, then check in formating of cell, what is year "sign" for "not basic" category of cell.

Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `;` as the separator (instead of `,`), I assume that your Locale settings are not "English".  You need to use the correct definition for your own country.

For example, while in English you use `"mm/yy"` ("Month / Year"), in German you would use `"mm/jj"` ("Monat / Jahr"), or in French `"mm/aa"` ("Mois / Année")